# WCF Clients performance issues

Tags: c#, wcf

I have an application that should be able to send hundreds of concurrent request to my wcf service.  The service is exposing http federation binding.

Currently I am using a single client and TPL to send requests on multiple threads. I have also changed the system.net max connections setting to 1000 so that windows is not restricting wcf to atmost 2 concurrent requests.

I can see that the initial request take more time because they are getting the authentication token etc, and then the request time generally begins to reduces significantly, but then I see some spikes intermittently, which do not correlate with the server logs i have.

I am wondering if this is the best way to approach a high throughup highly scalable client.

I have tried using sharing Client proxies among multiple threads and sharing ChannelFactory among multiple threads. All threads are done using TPL.

The binding is shown

```
<basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="Binding1" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:05:00" closeTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
```

Comment: How many CPUs does your test client machine have?  Generally, if you want to do true load testing you need to run multiple machines as you will run into processing restrictions on your client machine trying to generate all the threads and requests.

Comment: i have a quad core 8 gb box as client machine, and i really not stressing the box, i run 10 threads sending 100 requests each but and hope that for a samll period server will spike, but it doesnt

Comment: If you wish, you can decrease the "warm up" period by increasing the thread pool's min threads.  .net will immediately increase up to the min then meter out until the max at something like 2 threads per second.

Answer (score 2):

You mention you are using a single client instance and then fanning out work using TPL. WCF client instances are technically not thread safe. The cost of creating a client is extremely cheap and you should not be afraid of creating new instances so long as you `Close()` them when you're done.

Next, you should not be using TPL alone to get you the concurrency. When you're making WCF calls, it's all about network I/O and waiting on the response from the server. What you need to make sure you're doing in your client is using [async WCF contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734701.aspx). You can then combine these with TPL's `Task.Factory.FromAsync` to chain together any other workflow you might need to perform after the call returns. For example:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService
{
    [OperationContract(AsyncPattern=true)]
    IAsyncResult BeginDoSomething();
    SomeResultType EndDoSomething(IAsyncResult result);
}

// Somewhere in the client app you store your channel factory (these are "expensive", these you cache)
ChannelFactory<IMyService> channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IMyService>();

public void MyClientMethod()
{
   // Create a client channel
   IMyService myServiceChannel = channelFactory.CreateChannel();

   // Use TPL's FromAsync to invoke the async WCF call and wrap that up with the familiar Task API
   Task<SomeResultType>.Factory.FromAsync(myServiceChannel.BeginDoSomething
                                          myServiceChannel.EndDoSomething,
                                          null)
                               .ContinueWith(antecdent =>
                               {
                                    try
                                    {
                                        // NOTE: exception will be thrown here if operation failed
                                        SomeResultType result = antecedent.Result;

                                        // ... continue processing the result ...
                                    }
                                    finally
                                    {
                                        // NOTE: depending on your configuration you might want to watch for errors and .Abort() here too
                                        ((IClientChannel)myServiceChannel).Close();
                                    }
                               });      
}
```

All of your scalability is going to come from using the async I/O on that client call.

Comment: in my testing the transient client is always the worse performing, and takes the most cpu, reason might be that it has to go get a token from ADFS in our case. Also whenver i have shared client between threads, threading has never been an issue, but good pointer on TPL and Async

Comment: You're just getting lucky then. There are many pieces of shared state within a client instance where you can get burned. As with any kind of concurrency problem it may not always happen due to timing. As far as your authentiction is concerned, there should be ways to mitigate that as well. Can you update your question with exact details about your binding configuration? Also, are you using a single ChannelFactory instance?

Comment: that might be the case, I am sure we creating channel factory new everytime, do you think that might cause poor response times ?

Comment: The ChannelFactory should absolutely be cached once it's created. At bare minimum, you want to construct it once before you start your parallel work and just call CreateChannel on it in the parallel branches. If you were ever creating the ChannelFactory in the parallel branches that would have caused severe overhead. Going further, the best thing to do in your case where autehntication is part of the cost of starting to communicate would be to actually reuse the client instances such that you have one dedicated to each TPL thread. That way you incur the cost of Open()ing the channel only once.

Comment: How's it going after making some of my recommended changes? Is this answer sufficient?

Comment: seems like instances of client base should be thread safe or so says this post http://blogs.msdn.com/b/drnick/archive/2007/12/18/concurrent-channel-performance.aspx, my best option seems to be to use user name/password security with a cached channel factory, although its only marginally better than using a single client for all requests. Its amazing how slow WCF is though, it almost takes 200 ms on average (over 10K reqeusts with 25 threads) to communicate with service ( after subtracting the server time)

Comment: Wait, you're using ClientBase<T> proxies??? I would avoid those and just use ChannelFactory<T> w/GetChannel directly. I assumed you were on a path where you had started to change your code to use what I was suggesting. I really can't help if we're not talking about the same code cause I'm confused on what implementation you're actually working with at this point. If you can add some sample code that show the patterns you're using at this point I can maybe help further. Also details on your full WCF binding would be helpful because there's a lot of potential perf pitfalls in the binding realm.

Answer (score 1):

Some production performance issues with both WCF services and using the WCF clients (ClientBase or ChannelFactory directly) are due to the .NET garbage collector being forced to do a lot of work because of sloppy object disposal. I'd use Performance Monitor to check the behavior of the .NET garbage collector at runtime to see if this is causing the spikes.

If it is a GC issue then you need to do a review of your service and client code. On the service, ensure object instance scope is as limited as possible. This helps ensure instance are mostly garbage collected in Gen0 which occurs most often. The client code should also be reviewed but it is particularly important in the service code.

Also, in both the service but particularly on the client, make sure object instances that implement IDisposable are properly wrapped in a `using` statement **EXCEPT for the WCF client instance**. To handle the proper disposal of the WCF client, look at this [brief blog post](http://omaralzabir.com/do-not-use-using-in-wcf-client/) for a good pattern. This can get tricky if you are using a dependency injection container. You can search for "WCF do not use using" for more detail information on why. The BasicHttpBinding and some configurations of the WsHttpBinding can handle sloppy disposal but any binding that uses sessions will be prone to the GC issues.